# Can we write group by to get first record of the order by in Oracle sql? Or can you suggest solution for given query?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

I have a table which shows good, bad and other status for a Device everyday. I want to display a row per device with today's status and **previous best status**('Good' if anytime good in the time span, otherwise the previous day status). I am using join and query is as shared below.

```
  SELECT t1.devid,
         t1.status AS Today_status,
         t2.status AS yest_status,
         t2.runtime AS yest_runtime
    FROM devtable t1
         INNER JOIN devtable t2
            ON     t1.devid = t2.devid
               AND t1.RUNTIME = '17-jul-2018'
               AND t2.runtime > '30-jun-2018'
ORDER BY t1.devID, (CASE WHEN t2.status LIKE 'G%' THEN 0 END), t2.runtime;
```

Now I am not able to group it to a single record per device(getting many records per device). Can you suggest a solution on this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include sample data and expected results, and which version of Oracle you are using. (Also, `'17-jul-2018'` is a string not a date; convert it explicitly to a date for comparison, or use a date literal like `date '2018-07-17'`.)

Comment: show your OP Tabel..

Comment: @AlexPoole Please Ignore about the date format I shared. I am using date conversion function. I am just looking for inputs or logic to solve the main problem. And trying to improve my knowledge on this front.

Comment: Again, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51377967/edit) to include sample data and expected results. I think I know what you're trying to do but data will clarify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to interpret with sample data and results, but it sounds like you want something like:

```
select devid, runtime, status, prev_status,
  coalesce(good_status, prev_status) as best_status
from (
  select devid, runtime, status,
    lag(status) over (partition by devid order by runtime) as prev_status,
    max(case when status = 'Good' then status end) over (partition by devid) as good_status
  from (
    select devid, runtime, status
    from devtable
    where runtime > date '2018-06-30'
  )
)
where runtime = date '2018-07-17';
```

The innermost query restricts the date range; if you need an upper bound on that (i.e. it isn't today as in your example) then include that as another filter.

The next layer out uses `lag()` and `max()` analytic functions to find the previous status, and any 'Good' status (via a case expression), for each ID.

The outer query then filters to only show the target end date, and uses `coalesce()` to show 'Good' if that existed, or the previous status if not.

Demo with some made-up sample data in a CTE:

```
with devtable (devid, runtime, status) as (
            select 1, date '2018-06-30', 'Good' from dual -- should be ignored
  union all select 1, date '2018-07-01', 'a' from dual
  union all select 1, date '2018-07-16', 'b' from dual
  union all select 1, date '2018-07-17', 'c' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2018-07-01', 'Good' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2018-07-16', 'e' from dual
  union all select 2, date '2018-07-17', 'f' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2018-07-01', 'g' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2018-07-16', 'Good' from dual
  union all select 3, date '2018-07-17', 'i' from dual
  union all select 4, date '2018-07-01', 'j' from dual
  union all select 4, date '2018-07-16', 'k' from dual
  union all select 4, date '2018-07-17', 'Good' from dual
)
select devid, runtime, status, prev_status,
  coalesce(good_status, prev_status) as best_status
from (
  select devid, runtime, status,
    lag(status) over (partition by devid order by runtime) as prev_status,
    max(case when status = 'Good' then status end) over (partition by devid) as good_status
  from (
    select devid, runtime, status
    from devtable
    where runtime > date '2018-06-30'
  )
)
where runtime = date '2018-07-17';

     DEVID RUNTIME    STAT PREV BEST
---------- ---------- ---- ---- ----
         1 2018-07-17 c    b    b   
         2 2018-07-17 f    e    Good
         3 2018-07-17 i    Good Good
         4 2018-07-17 Good k    Good
```

You could remove the innermost query by moving that filter into the case expression:

```
select devid, runtime, status, prev_status,
  coalesce(good_status, prev_status) as best_status
from (
  select devid, runtime, status,
    lag(status) over (partition by devid order by runtime) as prev_status,
    max(case when runtime > date '2018-06-30' and status = 'Good' then status end)
      over (partition by devid) as good_status
  from devtable
)
where runtime = date '2018-07-17';
```

but that would probably do quite a lot more work as it would examine and calculate a lot of data you don't care about.

Comment: Wah ! Thanks a lot Alex .. Very nice solution; especially liked a lot about the concept of using case inside max. Suits my need correctly. And apologies in delay in accepting the answer and not sharing the exact table data(due to confidentiality).

Answer (score 0):

Analytic functions should do what you want.  It is unclear what your results should look like, but this gathers the information you need:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT d.*, 
             LAG(d.status) OVER (PARTITION BY d.devid ORDER BY d.runtime) as prev_status,
             LAG(d.runtime) OVER (PARTITION BY d.devid ORDER BY d.runtime) as prev_runtime,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.devid ORDER BY d.runtime) as seqnum,
             SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'GOOD' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY d.devid) as num_good
      FROM devtable d
      WHERE d.runtime = DATE '2018-07-17' AND
            d.runtime > DATE '2018-06-2018'
     ) d
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: This solution, showing error 'ORA00937 : not a single-group group function '.